# JavaFX application going slow switching between views in BorderPane

Tags: performance, javafx, view, borderpane

I find that switching between views in my app seems to go kind of slow (buttons are JFXButtons and have a "push" animation that seem to go anything but fluid).
The main stage is a BorderPane.
I basically have a side bar (left pane in BorderPane) with different buttons that will load an AnchorPane in the center of a BorderPane. In the code below Home.fxml is loaded in the center of the BorderPane.

The switching of the views is done in the MenuController (controller of the button sidebar)

The code when pressing one button is the following:

```
@FXML
void homeAction(ActionEvent event) {

    Runnable setHome = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                root = Main.getRoot();
                home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/Home.fxml"));

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {     
                        root.setCenter(home);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error loading Home.fxml");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread setHomeThread = new Thread(setHome);
    setHomeThread.start();
}
```

The loaded view does not do anything such as connecting to a db. It just shows an empty tableview, a label and a button...and it seems performance could be much better.

Is there something I´m missing or anything wrong with the code above?

Comment: Why the `Thread` to do this?

Comment: As I understand any action must be done using a thread and, if UI is updated, modified or created it should be inside the JAVAFX main thread Platform...This would decouple JAVAFX main thread for UI from other processing done for other reason. This should make the UI in JAVAFX more fluid... But maybe I get it wrong...

Comment: There is no need to load an `FXML` using a `Thread` unless you expect it to take a long time to load. You said you don't have many `Nodes` in the `FXML` so it should not take long to load them.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that tip. Nonetheless, would using a thread for this imply in a bad performance? I have change the code of one of the views without a thread and have tested switching between view with thread and view without thread and the performance seems to be the same. Sorry, not the performance but the button animation...maybe is something implicit in the JFXButton properties...

Comment: Performance can be slow if you have a lot of unnecessary `Threads` running. From the code you posted, I can't see why you would have a performance issue. I would profile the app if I were you. I don't know if you use Netbeans but -> https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I´m basically using a thread for each action launched in the app and maybe this is wrong.

Comment: @user6127833 Yes... that's wrong. Use threads to execute long-running tasks in the background. Even then, you should use an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to manage the threads you create. But it seems here you don't need to use any background threads at all.

Comment: So, any time I use a thread for a specific long-running task, should I make use of an Executor? I understand an Executor should be implemented only when more than one thread must be run at a time...

Comment: This is, to control concurrency...